# Having problem in coding Arduino Uno

Tags: programming, c++, arduino-uno

I'm making a timer program which takes the Time Duration as input from the user by two button switches (one for 'up' and one for 'down'), and after pressing an another button switch ('start'), the timer starts. During countdown, an LED glows, and after the end of the countdown, it turns off.

The elapsed time is displayed on a 7 seg. display, as a minute count.

```cpp
#define segA 2
#define segB 3
#define segC 4
#define segD 5
#define segE 6
#define segF 7
#define segG 8
#define pinsig 0

const int buttonPinUp = 12;
const int buttonPinDown = 10;
const int buttonPinStart = 9;

int COUNT=0;
int buttonStateUp = 0;
int buttonStateDown = 0;
int buttonStateStart = 0;
int flag;

void setup()
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++)
    {
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
    pinMode(pinsig, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPinUp, INPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPinDown, INPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPinStart, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    buttonStateUp = digitalRead(buttonPinUp);
    if (buttonStateUp == HIGH)
    {
        COUNT++;
        delay(200);
    }
    buttonStateDown = digitalRead(buttonPinDown);
    if (buttonStateDown == HIGH)
    {
        COUNT--;
        delay(200);
    }
    buttonStateStart = digitalRead(buttonPinStart);
    if (buttonStateStart == HIGH)
    {
        flag = HIGH;
    }

    if (flag == HIGH)
    {
        if (COUNT > 0)
        {
            digitalWrite(pinsig, HIGH);
            COUNT--;
            delay(2000);
        }
        if (COUNT == 0)
        {
            flag = LOW;
            digitalWrite(pinsig, LOW);
        }
    }

    switch (COUNT)
    {
        case 0:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
            break;
        case 1:
            digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
            break;
        case 2:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
        case 3:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segF, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
        case 4:
            digitalWrite(segA, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
        case 5:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
        case 6:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
        case 7:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, LOW);
            break;
        case 8:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
        case 9:
            digitalWrite(segA, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segB, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segC, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segD, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segE, LOW);
            digitalWrite(segF, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(segG, HIGH);
            break;
    }
}
```

But the program is not working as I expected.
I'm new in programming, so know a little basics. Can anyone help me in that ?

Comment: Have you tried to have a program to only light the LED for a hardcoded amount of time?

Comment: Yes. I've used 'delay' function to lit up an LED for a certain duration.

Comment: This will only run while you hold the start button, and will only update after each minute, but you won't see anything until you've held it down for a full minute.  Your program is full of oddly redundant statements.

Comment: You also need to describe exactly how the program **is** working...don't just say "not as I expected".

Comment: This code is messy with really bad indention. Are you sure you want a `delay(60000)`? You'll have to wait a minute before your code moves on. I think what you need to do here is create some type of state machine diagram. You're rushing the process of development of code and jump straight into writing a script. That's bad practice.

Comment: It is taking the 'Up' and 'Down' input. But, after pressing the 'Start ' button, after 1 minute the display counts just 1 minute. Nothing is happening after that.

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example in IDE Examples menu

Comment: what is the purpose of `COUNT = COUNT;`?

Comment: as chris mentioned it will only run when you hold the start button, you can define a boolean and when start button pressed change that to `TRUE` and `IF` that's true rest of your code will run, `ELSE` do something else... also change that 1 minute delay to 10 seconds for testing, you can increase it later on...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I made some changes in my code. But, I didn't have the idea about defining a boolean, I used  an integer 'flag' (experimentally), which remains HIGH, even after releasing the Start button, until the countdown is completed. It served the purpose properly. Now the program is working as expected. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I re-indented your code in order to make it human-readable (we are humans here). In doing so, I noticed an extra closing brace. If your code doesn't compile, that's the reason. If it does compile, please, make sure that the code you post is **the same** as the one you are discussion in your question.

Comment: I properly didn't know the formatting code for uploading c++ programming code here. Thank you for editing that in a proper way, Mr. Edgar Bonet. Now it looks normal to me too. And yes, there was an unnecessary closing brace in the program. I deleted it from my program, after seeing the compilation error. I forgot to change it here. Sorry about that. But, the actual problem in the working of my project was for a different reason. I didn't use the 'flag' in the code (for keeping the switch case function running). Now, after using that 'flag', it is running properly.

Comment: To format your code, press Control-T in the IDE.  It handles all that infection for you and makes brave errors stick out like a sore thumb.